# Google Analytics Embed API issue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

i created a page on my website that showing my google analytics report. Actually i just modified some of this demo https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/.

It's working good, but when i have too much tables and chart of some dimension and metrics, some tables and data are not appear. Is there anyone know how to fix this, or someone know how to get all the data in a different way?

Here is my code

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

// authorize google account
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});

// view selector
var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-container'
});

viewSelector.execute();

// date range
var dateRange = {
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday'
};

// date range selector
var dateRangeSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.DateRangeSelector({
    container: 'date-range-selector-container'
})
.set(dateRange)
.execute();

// configuration for line chart
var chart1Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// configuration for operation system
var chart2Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:operatingSystem',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '10'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

var chart3Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:operatingSystem, ga:operatingSystemVersion',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '15'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// config for browser
var chart4Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:browser',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '10'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

var chart5Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:browser, ga:browserVersion',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '15'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// mobile
var chart6Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:mobileDeviceBranding',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '10'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

var chart7Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:mobileDeviceBranding, ga:mobileDeviceModel',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '15'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// audience
var chart8Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:userAgeBracket',
      sort: '-ga:sessions'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

var chart9Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:userGender',
      sort: '-ga:sessions'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// Pageviews
var chart10Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:pageviews, ga:uniquePageviews, ga:timeOnPage',
      dimensions: 'ga:pagePath, ga:pageTitle',
      sort: '-ga:pageviews',
      'max-results': '20'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// traffic sources
var chart11Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:fullReferrer',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '15'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

var chart12Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:keyword',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '15'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// geo network
var chart13Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:networkLocation',
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': '10'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'TABLE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// graph user
var chart14Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:users',
      dimensions: 'ga:userType',
      sort: '-ga:users'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'PIE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
};

// chart 1
var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart1Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container'}});

// chart 2 (Operation System)
var dataChart2 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart2Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-2'}});

var dataChart3 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart3Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-3'}});

var dataChart4 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart4Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-4'}});

var dataChart5 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart5Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-5'}});

var dataChart6 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart6Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-6'}});

var dataChart7 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart7Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-7'}});

var dataChart8 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart8Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-8'}});

var dataChart9 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart9Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-9'}});

var dataChart10 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart10Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-10'}});

var dataChart11 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart11Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-11'}});
var dataChart12 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart12Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-12'}});

var dataChart13 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart13Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-13'}});

var dataChart14 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(chart14Config)
    .set({query: dateRange})
    .set({chart: {container: 'chart-container-user'}});

// date range selector
dateRangeSelector.on('change', function(data) {
    dataChart.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart2.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart3.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart4.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart5.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart6.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart7.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart8.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart9.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart10.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart11.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart12.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart13.set({query: data}).execute();
    dataChart14.set({query: data}).execute();

    var datefield = document.getElementById('from-dates');
    datefield.innerHTML = data['start-date'] + '&mdash;' + data['end-date'];
});

// render chart every view changed
viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart2.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart3.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart4.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart5.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart6.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart7.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart8.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart9.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart10.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart11.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart12.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart13.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
    dataChart14.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
});


});
```

Is there a way to retrieve all of the data requested until the page fully load and then show them up?

Comment: Do you mean you want to wait until all the charts are fully ready before displaying any of them on the page? It's not quite clear what you're asking for.

Comment: yes, like that. How can i do that?